# simple child routing in angular 2

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do child routing in angular 2 on login button just for checking purpose, but it gives me this

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'sign-up'

Here's the code of routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [

      {
        path: '',
        component : LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,
        children: [
          {path: "", redirectTo:"sign-up", pathMatch:"full"},
          {path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent}
        ]
      }
    ];
```

And here is my login template

```
 <div class="row signup-centerClass loginform">
    <form>
      <div class="col col-md-12">

        <label>Username or email :
          <font color="#FF6600">*</font>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="uname" [(ngModel)]="Username" placeholder="Example:Haris Wakeel">

        <label>Password :
          <font color="#FF6600">*</font>
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="uname" [(ngModel)]="Username" placeholder="Example:Haris Wakeel">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 280px; text-align: center; font-size: 15px">Login</button>
        <p style="color: #666; font-size: 15px; margin-top: 5px" ><strong>Don't have an account?</strong>
          <a [routerLink]="['/sign-up']"><strong>Sign-up</strong></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: The empty-path route should redirect to /login.

Comment: There is indeed no route matching /signup. There is one matching / (the first one); there is one matching /login (the second one), which redirects to /login/signup; and there is one matching /login/signup.

Comment: so how can I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the route as like below,

```
{
    path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,
        children: [
            { path: "", redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: "full" },
            { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent , pathMatch: "full" }
        ]
}
```

Comment: same error

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'sign-up'

Comment: Thanks, but I got the solution, Here it is , I missed the base path

  {path: '', redirectTo:"login", pathMatch:"full"},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,
    children:[
      {path:"sign-up", component:SignUpComponent}
    ]
  }

Comment: Mark if it has helped